# Disable the instance of DUT from Test-bench

Tags: system-verilog

Please help to resolve one issue that I am facing connected with disabling DUT instanced.
My DUT top module has many instances in it, but my test does not need them. 
Is there any way to disable these instances from test-bench.

For example this is my DUT module prototype:

```
module top (…….);

// instances needs to be disabled
module1 #(16) inst1 (.CLK(clk_100),.PAD_RSTN(ext_reset_n),.RSTN(global_reset_n));
module2 #(16) inst2 (.CLK(clk_100),.PAD_RSTN(ext_reset_n),.RSTN(pcie_reset_n));
pcie_module #(…) inst_pci (…..);

// main test target instances
target_testmodule #(…) test_inst(…);
child1_of_target_testmodule #(…) test_inst_child1(…);
child2_of_target_testmodule #(…) test_inst_child2(…);

endmodule
```

so my test-bench will only test the target_testmodule and its child modules.
I am using bind to connect the interface to target_testmodule and then starting to drive the pins of target_testmodule. And the target_testmodule drives its child module pins.

So for this test I don’t need pci_module instace or other instaces, because they are big instances take much time, provides lots of warning and also they drive some of the target_testmodule ports which I don’t neet.

My question is there some mechanism to disable the pci module from the test-bench. I don’t have write permission to top module to comment the instances or put them inside `ifdefs.

Answer (score 1):

- Your first mechanism is to ask the person who locked the file to change it so you can get your job done more efficiently. They can put in `generate` or `ifdef` statements for you.
- If you had separate clock or enables signals, you could force them to an inactive state
- copy and modify a local copy of the top-level file and have that file used instead. The are a number of ways to substitute the local module

Comment: Thanks Dave much. 
I was hoping the System verilog gives some option here like binding the instances that I dont need to NULL or forcing the whole instance to empty.
Currently I am using `ifndef SIM_REMOVE method in top

Answer (score 1):

Beyond getting write permission, the next easiest way would be to make you own top.

Verilog (since IEEE1364-2001) and SystemVerilog do have a way to compile different modules of the same name into different libraries, then use a configuration to decided which one will be used during elaboration. You could use this technique to use swap the module instances you don't want with simplified or dummy version. Depending your testing environment is configured, implementing this configurations can be tricky. If you are up for the challenge, then read [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 33. *Configuring the contents of a design*

Comment: Thanks Greg, this is also another nice opiton!